# Svelte Substitution in <script> within svelte:head

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

I'm using svelte to create a personal website. I want to place a chunk of javascript code in the head of my final HTML code, which is based on a svelte component. So I have something like

```
<svetle:head>
    <script> var url = "myurl.com/"; </script>
<svetle:head>
```

within a `[slug].svelte` file. I want to substitute a value that passed into this component as a prop within the script. I tried doing something like

```
<svetle:head>
    <script> var url = "myurl.com/{post.slug}"; </script>
<svetle:head>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. If the substitution `{post.slug}` were to occur outside of `<script>`, svelte would perform the substitution just fine, before passing the resulting html to the client. However because it's within the `<script>`, svelte seems to be assuming that I must want literally `"myurl.com/{post.slug}"`, instead of `"myurl.com/my-post-name"` . I think this may be because `{}` has meaning in javascript.

Note that I've tried every combination of `"myurl.com/{post.slug}"`, `"myurl.com/"{post.slug}`, `myurl.com/${post.slug}`. Any placement of `{post.slug}` within `<script>` does not substitute.

How can I get svelte to perform this substitution at the same time it performs every other substitution in the `.svelte` component? I can't imagine there isn't a way to do this, but the svelte documentation doesn't seem to address this.

Comment: Have you tried using `\`myurl.com/${post.slug}\``? It is called a [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Yes, I did try that. It seems like there is no way to do this in svelte. I ended up finding a different work around.

Comment: If you did, please post it as an answer so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 4):

Seemingly you can inject your script via @html svelte function.

```js
<script lang="ts">
    const postSlug: string = "...";
</script>

<svelte:head>

    {@html `<script>
        var url = "${postSlug}";
    </script>`}

</svelte:head>
```

One downside is that this whole `<script/>` block will need to render as a string then. Which would make it hard to manage larger JS logic. But it works for my case when injecting env variables into simple `<script/>` blocks.

Comment: The script won't execute on page navigation when using @html.

Answer (score 2):

This is kinda janky, but if the value you need is a text string, you could put it inside a `<meta>` tag, then select it.

```
<svelte:head>
  <meta name="myVar" content={post.slug} />
  <script>
    var url = document.querySelector('meta[name=myVar]')
    console.log(url.getAttribute('content'))
  </script>
</svelte:head>
```

However, I suspect there's probably a much better way to do this without such a workaround, and knowing a bit more about how the code will consume the variable would be helpful in providing a better answer.